# Why did Frank Drake choose these math equations for the Voyager Golden Record?

Tags: arithmetic

Not sure this belongs in this or some other community, but one of the images on the golden record is a brief snapshot of our decimal system and then a few math examples. Here is the image in question:

http://webodysseum.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Voyager-Golden-Record-Pictures-03.gif

Is there a reason he chose these values to show how we do arithmetic? Does is introduce concepts that other equations would lack? Just curious... also I might get a tattoo of this so I'd like to know more about the background of it first. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

At a guess, $2+3=5$ is the simplest non-confusing sum: $2+2=4$ is confusable with multiplication. $1+2=3$ is confusable with an ordering, as is $1+1=2$. It looks like all of the digits are used in the calculations, too.

Comment: That is pretty insightful, what books or internet sources would you recommend for a reading list?

Comment: Well, that's certainly one way of looking at it... Another way would be that of a very proud and highly advanced civilization of alien warriors, receiving a deeply insulting message from an unknown planet, not-so-subtly insinuating that they don't even know how to add and count... Or, alternately, a peaceful race of celestial beings, wondering about why one Earth $($no pun intended$)$ would anyone develop *two* signs for separating primes $(+$ and $=)$... I guess certain things are inevitably [lost in translation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0335266)... ;-$)$

Comment: @Lucian that is nothing, [the shape of our continents spells out "Dean Fusk is embezzeling the canteen fund" in Centravian](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cult/comics/2000adstrips/drandquinch/drandquinch06.shtml). But the 8+17=25 would convince them about the primes.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer can be found in this passage from Drake's chapter, "The Foundations of the Voyager Record," in [*Murmurs of Earth*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345315367), a popular book edited by Carl Sagan which came out at around the time of the Voyager launchings:

> "About this time [1961] *Lingua Cosmica*, a book on interstellar
>   codes, was published by Hans Freudenthal, a Yale mathematician.  It
>   contained an ingenious method to construct a language by utilizing
>   simple mathematics to establish simple rules and concepts.  For
>   example, an equation such as $2+3=5$ and another equation such as
>   $4+5=9$ can be used to establish the meaning of the plus sign and the
>   equal sign....  Freudenthal showed that by using such
>   mathematical equations one could develop quite a sophisticated
>   language -- in fact even an ability in the end to express emotion."

The book by Freudenthal that Drakes cites is actually titled [*Lincos: Design of a Language for Cosmic Intercourse Part I*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincos_(artificial_language)).  ("Lincos" is a contraction of "Lingua Cosmica.")  Freudenthal's book is in the tradition of Russell and Whitehead's *Principia Mathematica*, with pages and pages of logical impenetralia.  There is no *Part II*.

Incidentally, there is a fun 1961 essay, [*Extraterrestrial Linguistics*,](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1338&context=wordways) by Solomon Golomb of [polyomino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) fame.  Here's an excerpt (with an interpolated "[more]" to make sense of one of the sentences):

> "[I]t is probably rank terrestrial provincialism to expect others to
>   attach the same importance to *pi* that we do.  Even in our own
>   mathematics, such constants as *e* and *log 2* are considered [more]
>   important, and the exaggerated role of *pi* stems largely from the
>   Greeks' undue efforts attempting to square the circle....
>
> "My own recommendation is the prime sequence $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23,\ldots$, with a long period to prove the non-accidental nature
>   of the signal.  It isn't so much that I'm sure these
>   Extra-terrestrials would *recognize* the primes; but if they don't,
>   they must be dull fellows, and I would just as soon uot [sic] get
>   acquainted."